# Bigcommerce Stencil - Display Latest Blog Post on Homepage

Tags: bigcommerce

How could I display the latest blog post on homepage?

I've already saw the question [Bigcommerce Stencil - Display Blog Posts on Homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414226/bigcommerce-stencil-display-blog-posts-on-homepage) and tried it.

But it doesn't show the post body.

My code

```
blog:
    recent_posts:
        limit: 1
        summary: 100
```

....

```
{{#each blog.recent_posts}}
            <h2>{{title}}</h2>
            <p>{{body}}</p>
            <a href="{{url}}">view more &gt;&gt;</a>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The front matter variables for the blog only expose a summary and not the full post text/content.

Comment: And how to show summary? 
{{summary}} doesn't work

Comment: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/front-matter-variables#Front-ref-blog